# What does the student pilot have to do during his/her PPL practical course?

Tags: flight-training, ppl

The PPL theory consists of:

- Principles of flight.
- Flight performance and planning.
- Aircraft general knowledge.
- Meteorology, Navigation, Flight Planning and Monitoring
- VFR Communications
- Human Performance and Limitations
- Air Law

I was wondering, what does the student pilot have to do during his/her PPL practical course?

It would be nice to see a list of things that needs to be mastered. A link to a practical resource would also help.

Comment: Please tag your question with a governing region (FAA, EASA, etc) so that we can give a more specific answer.

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the jurisdiction/governing body that is issuing the license but for the FAA you can find a [full list of everything covered on the Private Pilot Check Ride here](https://www.faa.gov/training_testing/testing/acs/media/private_airplane_acs.pdf) your training should cover those topics and maneuvers. *How* they are covered is up to your instructor.

Answer (score 1):

For the UK, the EASA PPL requirement for SEP(A) are listed [here](https://www.caa.co.uk/General-aviation/Pilot-licences/EASA-requirements/PPL-SPL-BPL/PPL-(A)-requirements/)

> If you don’t already hold a licence, you will need to complete 45
>   hours of flight instruction on aeroplanes, 5 hours of which may have
>   been completed in an approved flight simulator (an FSTD – flight
>   simulation training device), including at least:
>
> 1. 25 hours of dual flight instruction,
> 2. 10 hours of supervised solo flight time, including at least 5 hours of solo  cross country flight time with at least 1 cross country flight of at least 270 km (150 NM) that includes full stop landings at 2 aerodromes different from the departure aerodrome.
>
> You will need to complete a skill test after you have completed all
>   the flying requirements.
>
> You will also need to ensure that the examiner meets the requirements
>   for test notification and designation as set out in:
>
> ```
> IN 2014/110 (for UK examiners)
> IN 2015/050 (for non-UK examiners)
> ```

The list on the left of that page also lists requirements for other EASA licence types.

Non-EASA aricraft can be flown under an NPPL in the UK.  An outline of the NPPL is listed [here](https://www.caa.co.uk/General-aviation/Pilot-licences/UK-national-licences/NPPL--national-private-pilot-licence/)